# Sql select with outer join in same table

Tags: sql, derby

Can any one help for a query to select a student who entered only in specific subject and not in other subjects. Suppose I say only in "Eng.Maths".

```
STUDENT SUBJECT     MARK
Vels    Eng.Maths   60
Vels    Data.Mining 65
Stivel  Eng.Maths   55
Stivel  Data.Mining 69
Raj     Eng.Maths   66
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
WHERE subject = 'Eng.Maths'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table1 t2
                WHERE t1.Student = t2.Student
                AND t2.Subject <> t1.subject)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3e04d/2)

Comment: Change to `AND t2.Subject <> 'Eng.Maths'` in subselect.

Comment: Thanks. `SELECT NULL FROM` doesn't work in derby but `select * from table1 t2` works.